# Selecting columns for mathematical expression

Tags: regex, pandas

I am working with this data:

```
url1 = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dothemathonthatone/maps/master/bev_parse.csv'
df_bev = pd.read_csv(url1, index_col=0)

url2 = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dothemathonthatone/maps/master/frucht_parse.csv'
df_frucht = pd.read_csv(url2, index_col=0)

fertility = pd.merge(df_bev, df_frucht, on=['regional_schlüssel', 'year'])
```

and now I would like to filter columns using regex and divide them; using the data below that was provided on another Stackoverflow question. This part works fine...

```
denominator = fertility.filter(regex='^[a-z]+\d+$')                   # Lower case ones
denominator = denominator.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

this part does not work so well. with this code I am trying to select columns of the form Aus_15-20, Deu15_20, ..., Aus45_50, Deu45_50

```
numerator = fertility.filter(regex='^[A-Z][a-z]+\d+$')
numerator = numerator.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')  # Fix numbers
```

For some reason I am not picking up the columns in the `numerator`

the last code snipit is

```
numerator.div(denominator).add_prefix('fertility_')

fertility = fertility[['year', 'regional_schlüssel']].join(numerator.div(denominator).add_prefix('fertility_'))

fertility['reg_schl'] = fertility['regional_schlüssel']
```

I am new to using regex and i.loc; I want to get better at using them. Can someone tell me what the problem. The code worked fine until I changed the columns in the data set, and now I can not get it back.

Comment: Try `^[A-Z][a-z]+_?\d+[-_]\d+$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Sweet! It works! thanks! What is the '?' btw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+_?\d+[-_]\d+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M2dnCY/1) and the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5BA-Z%5D%5Ba-z%5D%2B_%3F%5Cd%2B%5B-_%5D%5Cd%2B%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
- `[a-z]+` - one or more lowercase ASCII letters
- `_?` - an optional (1 or 0) `_` char
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `[-_]` - a `-` or `_`
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: What tool or website did you use to generate that graphic? +1  That is really cool.

Comment: @ScottBoston The link to the site is in the answer, [Regulex](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5BA-Z%5D%5Ba-z%5D%2B_%3F%5Cd%2B%5B-_%5D%5Cd%2B%24).